# Making a recursive call from the loop macro

Tags: loops, recursion, lisp, common-lisp

I'm pretty new to common lisp and I've been stuck on a particular problem. The function I'm suppose to write takes in two parameters: a function and a List. It iterates through the list and calls the given function on each element in the list. If the function returns true then the element is added to a sub list that is returned

What I've tried so far is:

```
(defun myFunc(f l)
  (loop for x in l
        if (listp x) do (myFunc f x)
        else if (eql t (funcall f x))
        collect x
        )
  )
```

The function I've been given for f takes a parameter and if it's is an number, returns true. So far my code works if aList is a simple list such as (1 2 3). However when I input a nested list like (1 2 (4 5) 7) only (1 2 7) is outputted rather than (1 2 (4 5) 7).

I'm assuming it has something to do with my recursive call and what is returning. Would really appreciate some help on this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of minor issues. First off, I assume it's just a typo, but you need to replace `aFunc` with `f` (as there's no variable `aFunc` in your code).

Now to the main point of the question. In your `else if` branch, you correctly `collect` the value when the predicate is true. But in your recursive case, you simply run some code and discard the result. You're going to want to `collect` there too.

```
(defun myFunc (f l)
  (loop for x in l
        if (listp x)
          collect (myFunc f x)
        else if (eql t (funcall f x))
          collect x))
```

Finally, just a style note. It's generally more idiomatic to treat a predicate as true if it returns anything truthy, not just `t`. So if I was writing this, I'd probably replace `(eql t (funcall f x))` with simply `(funcall f x)`. If this is a homework assignment and the teacher told you to do it the other way, stick with that. But if it's for your benefit, you may consider changing that as well.